# Nodejs and Express routing, relative paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Was following the below tutorial on learing node.
http://mherman.org/blog/2015/08/24/node-express-swig-mongo-primer/#.V2jif1UrLIU

Have a route set up like this in file **api.js**

```
router.get('/hero',function(req,res,next){

    sh.find(function(err,hero){

        console.log(sh);
        res.render('api', {title: 'Superhero API', hero : hero});
    });

});
```

And the view **api.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/api/hero" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Superhero name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>


    <hr><br>

    <h2>All Superheros</h2>

    <ul>
    {%  for h in hero %}
      <li> <a href="hero/{{h.id}}">{{ h.name}} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

the first part of view is the form to enter new heros. The bottom part is to display list of people.

My doubt is the link. The link is `a href="hero/{{h.id}}">` . this will link to `/api/hero/:id.` How is this done? In the same page, for the form i have to enter the full path like `action="/api/hero"`

How does the routing work here or whats the difference?